# How to set height and margins of Radiobutton in WP with c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, radio-button

I'm creating radiobuttons in a windows Phone app programmatically with this:

```
int items = count / 2;
string[] ctrl= new string[items];
RadioButton [] radioButtons = new RadioButton[items];
for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
{
    radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton();
    radioButtons[i].Content = EffectsArray[i];
    stackPanelEffRadio.Children.Add(radioButtons[i]);
}
```

I would like to set margins and/or height on these radiobuttons with something like :

```
radiobuttons[i].Margin = .........
```

What would be the right way to do that ?

Comment: = new Thickness(...) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can set margins using `System.Windows.Thickness` eg:

```
radiobuttons[i].Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

Or, you could consider setting a style in your XAML...

Comment: I'm sorry, but newbie .. How do i mark as an answer ?

Comment: No worries, isn't there a button that says mark as answer? You need a certain amount of reputation to upvote, but I didn't think so for marking answers. More here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow